# Cloud Functions for Firebase - How to check whether a child exists?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have database structure on Firebase like this:

```
- members
    |- -kSjJSDFjl2DFc
          |- nationality: Australian

- statistics-nationality
    |- American : 2
```

And "members" is being monitored for onWrite when "nationality-stats" will be updated.

I have this code to get the current nationality value of the new member, and then navigate to statistics-nationality, but I want to know whether a particular nationality node exists or not to choose either set or update action:

```
const currentNationality = event.data.current.child("nationality").val();
const statisticsNationality = event.data.ref.parent.parent.child('statistics-nationality');
let statisticsNationalityChild = statisticsNationality.child(currentNationality);

if (statisticsNationalityChild.exists()) { // No such an exists() method
   // update
} else {
   // create new nationality
}
```

However, no `exists()` method at this line:

```
statisticsNationalityChild.exists()
```

Please advise how to check whether a child exists or not? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I see your data structure correctly, then `statistics-nationality` is not part of the event data that triggered the function. In that case you'll need to try and read the data to determine if it exists:

```
const currentNationality = event.data.current.child("nationality").val();
const statisticsNationality = event.data.ref.parent.parent.child('statistics-nationality');
let statisticsNationalityChild = statisticsNationality.child(currentNationality);

statisticsNationalityChild.once("value").then((snapshot) => {
  if (snapshot.exists()) { 
    // update
  } else {
    // create new nationality
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's not part of the event data. Thanks for the advice!